# excluding specific strings from regex search

Tags: python, regex, string

I have such a regex:

```
(&lt;.*?&gt;)
```

It allows me to find all the substrings starting with `&lt;` and ending with `&gt;`.

For instance, like the following:

```
&lt;IL_A_NUM&gt;
```

My regex expression helps me to find the strings as above. The expression `.*?` involves all characters, but I want to exclude strings with `&lt;` or `&gt;` inside from my search. So, if `&lt;` or `&gt;` appears between another `&lt;` and `&gt;` my search won't give me that subpart.

How should I modify my regular expression?

Comment: If you want to match the outer you just need to remove`?`.

Comment: My plan is, firstly finding the inner part, and replacing it with another string, and recursively proceeding until when I reach to the outer boundary. I want to replace the last outer part with another string anyway.

Comment: So just do this `re.sub(r'(&lt;)(.*)(&gt;)', r'\1your_last_character_to_replace\3', your_string)`

Comment: @yusuf Python's builtin `re` library doesn't support recursion/nested groupings... do you have some better examples of exactly what you're trying to achieve as this seems to be a bit of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Jon, I plan to do it recursively in a loop.

Comment: Thank you @Kasramvd, please share your comment as an answer, I will accept it. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching the outer sub-string you need to drop the `?` and for replacing the inner matched you can just use `re.sub` like following:

```
re.sub(r'(&lt;)(.*)(&gt;)', r'\1your_last_character_to_replace\3', your_string)
```